# Angular's recent version requires initialization for variables. How can I fix it?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, initialization

The code below works in the older Angular version.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
    <p>{{ value | reverse }}</p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  value: string;
}
```

However, the same code does not work in the recent version of Angular because of the errors below.

> Property 'value' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in
> the constructor.

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

> Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'.

When I looked up the solution for this issue, I could find two solutions: 1. use empty value for initialization({}, '', etc) 2. use safe-navigation operator (?). However, both of them don't work.

The first solution works only in certain situations, but not this one.

In addition, what should I do if the situation is where I can't even use the empty values for initialization. For an instance, if the 'value' variable above was an interface, I just can't attempt to initialize it.

Thank you,

Comment: `works in older version` does not mean that it was correct before (javascript just doesn't care unless it crashes on runtime). It most definitely just means that the compiler picks up more errors now (in the template). Where does the third error come from? And what do you mean by `both of them don't work`? Does that give an error? What is that error?

Comment: The third error is coming from [(ngModel)]="value"

When I said both of them work, it meant that the two solutions I found don't work because of the errors that I listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I would consider in this situation, is to have a default in the template utilzing the ng-container.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="value?.length > 0"></ng-container>
```

that way the reverse pipe is not expecting a undefined value. Angular is being preemptive here, so I tend to do the same in my template UI.